# NullPointerException on an instantiated object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test

I am running some test and for some reason, I am getting a nullpointerexception on the line below:

*"friendService.save(friend1);"*

```
    @DataJpaTest
    @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
    public class ServiceTests {

    @Autowired 
    FriendService friendService;


    @Test
    public void testCreateReadDelete() {


        Friend friend1 = new Friend("Gordon", "Moore");

        friendService.save(friend1);

        Iterable<Friend> friends = friendService.findAll();
        Assertions.assertThat(friends).extracting(Friend::getFirstName).containsOnly("Gordon");

        friendService.deleteAll();
        Assertions.assertThat(friendService.findAll()).isEmpty();


    }

}
```

Why might this be?

Comment: maybe the autowiring failed

Comment: Do post your Friend class

Comment: Your test isn't annotated with RunWith(SpringRunner.class). So it's not a Spring test, thus nothing is autowired.

Comment: `friendService` is `null` because it is the only variable that is dereferenced (`.` ). If `friend1` would be the problem, then the NPE would be thrown in the save method.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, once i added the RunWith(SpringRunner.class) annotation it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class ServiceTests {

    @Autowired 
    FriendService friendService;


    @Test
    public void testCreateReadDelete() {


        Friend friend1 = new Friend("Gordon", "Moore");

        friendService.save(friend1);

        Iterable<Friend> friends = friendService.findAll();
        Assertions.assertThat(friends).extracting(Friend::getFirstName).containsOnly("Gordon");

        friendService.deleteAll();
        Assertions.assertThat(friendService.findAll()).isEmpty();


    }

}
```